# GPON intentional sabotage

Tags: fiber

All ONTs on a single GPON eventually share the same fiber core.  It's light, so I anything entering the core travels both ways through PLCs, down to the ONTs and up to the OLC.

If one would continoulsy send rubbish on either 1310nm or 1490nm, would it mean the whole segment collapses?

I do understand any system can be broken as long as there is bad intention, but what if one individual - more innocently and common perhaps - accidentally connects a 1310nm media convertor?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fiber is split in the downstream (OLT to ONT) and combined in the upstream. Only the OLT will see what any end transmits.

You could, in theory, jam the upstream since that's the only signal you generate. High enough power could damage equipment.

Keep in mind, the operator can rather trivially tell who does this. And it would be highly illegal almost everywhere.

Comment: If one simply sends a continuous a 1,310nm wavelength, would it destroy the TDM slots and render the whole segment unusable until turned off?

Comment: How could I detect who is doing this?  The OTDR can't see more than 1 PLC down the line, could it?